# run postInstall script only on git in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm using `Angular 6` and below is the content of `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod --aot"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-toaster": "^1.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.3",
    "npm": "6.2.0"
  }
}
```

Whenever I install a new package using `npm`

```
npm install <package_name>
```

after installation of the package, the `postinstall` script is executed which in turn runs `build command` to build the application.

I had put that `postinstall` because the application is deployed on **Heroku** via **gitlab-ci**. so, every time a push is made it will run `npm install` on Heroku server followed by `postinstall` script.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - deploy

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=koober-angular --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
  only:
  - master
```

But since, this `postinstall` is running even in local development environment.

**How can I prevent it to run `postinstall` script in local development environment?**

Answer (score 1):

You should create environment specific command installation in `package.json` file.

package.json

```
"install:prod": "npm install"
"postinstall:prod": "ng build --prod --aot"
```

and add this command to `gitlab-ci.yml` file to auto deployment only for prod.

OR

if you dont want to change `gitlab-ci.yml` file then

```
"install:local": "npm install"
```

and use this command(`npm run install:local`) on local development environment

Comment: do you mean **prod branch** or **prod tag** in `gitlab-ci.yml` by **only for prod**?

Comment: only prod tag in gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: I used `"install:local": "npm install"` and when run `npm install` locally, it run `postinstall`. When I run `npm install:local` it gives command not found.

Comment: for that you have to run command with `npm run install:local`

Comment: even `npm run install:local` is running `postinstall`. I think because `install:local` is just an alias for `npm install` and `postinstall` is being triggered by `npm install`

Comment: ohh yes you are right, so try to use first option. and let me know if it works.